# How to generate POSTMAN authorization message for WCF using custom validation?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-security

I would like to create a POSTMAN script that would be able to send authorization request and then using token send another request to my web service to get some data. So far I struggle with generation custom authorization message.

What I have done so far: created my custom auhtorization class, modified accordingly web.config, snippets below.

**Custom authorization class**:

```
public class CustomUserCredentials : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
       //login logic
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="TestWebService.MyWebService">
            <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingSSL"
                contract="TestWebService.IMyWebService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBindingSSL">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
                    includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TestWebService.CustomValidate, TestWebService" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I started Fiddler while I was using console application to test my web service and made another snipper of the message. I tried to update created and expiration date and time for my new request, but it failed.
I can't figure out how or is it even possible to generate my own message to be able to retrieve token from the web service so I would be able to use it for my requests. All these secret keys and guids make me feel that WCF using some security rules to protect web service from bruting. I need somebody's advice, because I feel that I'm fighting with a windmill.

Another question, can I create 1 explicit action in my web service that won't be requiring authorization?

**Postman message body from my client to the web service:**

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d1bef246-a8ee-4b54-8760-917f53c56cd9</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://localhost:44389/MyWebService.svc</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2023-06-30T13:27:34.151Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2023-06-30T13:32:34.151Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-8045e6f4-075c-4423-9b65-f2c8ac49ebd0-1">
                <o:Username>login</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
            <t:Entropy>
                <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-1aa12825-4289-4483-ae2e-f32233771841-1" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">04CGZQUKM3Q6W59vUYnaTMSDDwXPW5+KoRaN0I/UHuI=</t:BinarySecret>
            </t:Entropy>
            <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is it possible to try to build a judgment method into WCF and send JSON requests by Postman with verification information and required parameters? Usually I use postman to send a post request with parameters to test the service, which should help you.

Comment: I agree,  but I'm working with a legacy that utilizes custom validation and I can't chage it at this point of time. I would like to test the web service using Postman, but I can't do it untill I pass authorization stage and receive a token for further requests.

Comment: First, you use UserNamePasswordValidator
X.509 certificate required. The password information is then encapsulated through the channelfactory. This way, user information is not stored in the header. The question is how does Postman send an X.509 certificate when sending a request? At the same time, our user information is not in the header (which is not secure), so there may be other ways to achieve it. In Postman there is a dedicated module for verifying the sending of information, and you may need to check the documentation to learn how to simulate channelfactory functionality.